# Doctrine -- Having MAX with query builder

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, query-builder

I'm trying to make this query with the query builder:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table
WHERE code_response <> 0
GROUP BY order_id
HAVING MAX(last_date_run)
```

But I didn't find how to do the **HAVING MAX** with the query builder:

I did that:

```
return $this->createQueryBuilder('i')
            ->where('i.codeResponse != :codeError')
            ->groupBy('i.order')
            ->having('lastDateRun');
    }
```

How can I do an **HAVING MAX** with the query builder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('i');

return $this
  ->createQueryBuilder('i')
  ->where('i.codeResponse != :codeError')
  ->groupBy('i.order')
  ->having($qb->expr()->max('i.lastDateRun'));
```

should work but I didn't tested